# What is the meaning of "mutually exclusive" terms in Boolean algebra?

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-operations

I was going through an article that talked about self-dual functions. It said that any boolean function is self-dual only if:

1. Number of min-terms equals the number of max-terms.
2. Function should not contain two mutually exclusive terms.

What is the meaning of "mutually exclusive" here? Please, if someone could explain the underlying logic behind "mutually exclusive" terms. In what sense are two boolean expressions "mutually exclusive"?

Thanks!

Link to article:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/self-dual-functions-in-digital-logic/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [this related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1602660/58610):

> A Boolean function is called *self-dual*, if it is negated by negating all inputs.

If the function contains two [minterms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_normal_form#Minterms) which contradict each other in every literal, it cannot be self-dual.

**Example:**

A 3-input function has the minterms `abc` and `!a!b!c`. Therefore, its function value is '1' for `a=1, b=1, c=1`. And it is also '1' for `a=0, b=0, c=0`. However, as a self-dual function it should be '0' for the latter combination of inverted inputs.

Comment: Okay I got it this. Thanks a lot. I had another question though. Can a function F and its compliment (F') have same dual though?